# secondary axis ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I am encountering some issues when defining a secondary axis in ggplot2.
In particular I can't define the transformation I would like to apply to the axis without quoting the data.

Here the code:

```
mtcars %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x=mpg, y=wt), col="red")+
  geom_line(aes(x=mpg, y=disp*( max(wt) / max(disp) ) ), col="blue" )+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./(max(wt) / max(disp)), name="disp"))
```

And I get the error:

```
Error in rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::f_rhs(self$trans), data = range, env = rlang::f_env(self$trans)) : 
object 'wt' not found
```

When defining `sec.axis = sec_axis(~./(max(wt) / max(disp))` the variable `wt` and `disp` are contained in the `mtcars` dataset. Why is it returning the error?

I can get around it by doing

```
... sec_axis(~./(max(mtcars$wt) / max(mtcars$disp)) ...
```

However I would like to apply these transformation without quoting the dataset every time. 
This is because before plotting the data I would like to apply some transformations such as

```
my_df %>% groupby(...) %>% summarize(...) %>% mutate(...) %>% ggplot(...)
```

When plottting the data in such way I cannot refer to an existing table because the table doesn't exit but it is being created for the sole purposes of plotting.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you must specify your dataset in `sec_axis`. I would therefore suggest you split your computation in two steps. First you do: `my_df <- my_df %>% groupby(...) %>% summarize(...) %>% mutate(...)`. Second you `ggplot` it. That should not make your code less readable or less maintainable IMHO.

Comment: The problem is I have to create a lot of plots and I would like to avoid creating so many temporary dfs

Comment: Just delete them after usage with `rm(my_df)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot with 2 y axes, one y axis on the left, and another y axis on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right)